# Using sed to replace line in perl

Tags: perl, sed, system

I want to uncomment the line 168 at etter.conf file. The command runs OK in terminal but I'm getting an error while trying it in perl.

```
system ("sed -i '168s/.*/redir_command_on = "iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i %iface -p tcp --dport %port -j REDIRECT --to-port %rport"/' /etc/etter.conf");
```

**Error is:**

```
Bareword found where operator expected at ./attack.pl line 135, near 
""sed -i '168s'/.*'/redir_command_on = "iptables"
```

I think is has something to do with the special characters and escapes.

Comment: You need to escape your nested quotes. Perl thinks that iptables is supposed to be variable.

Comment: The doublequotes in the command are terminating the perl string.

Comment: Is there a reason you're shelling out to `sed`? Perl is perfectly capable of updating a file all by itself.

Comment: You can even do 'inplace' editing in Perl, shelling out to sed is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So Perl is parsing along, and it finds a string literal

```
system ("sed -i '168s/.*/redir_command_on = "
        ^                                   ^
        |                                   |
        +-----------------------------------+
```

What's next should be `)` or an operator, but it's `iptables`. You didn't properly form your string literal. Switching delimiters will do the trick:

```
system(q{sed -i '168s/.*/redir_command_on = "..."/' /etc/etter.conf})
```

(`q{...}` is the same as `'...'`.)

By the way, using the "list form" for `system` is better since it avoids starting and using a shell needlessly,

```
system('sed', '-i', '168s/.*/redir_command_on = "..."/', '/etc/etter.conf')
```

Comment: nice, you can also replace `system(q{...` with `system(qw{...` to automatically get a list form.

Comment: @steabert, No. You'll get a list, but it won't be the right command.

Comment: ah, because of the spaces?

Comment: @steabert, Yes. `qw` splits on whitespace. It doesn't know anything about shell literals.

Answer (score 1):

You can't nest bare double quotes in a double quoted string. Perl has more [quoting operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) you can use.

```
# Instead of
system ("sed -i '168s/.*/redir_command_on = "iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i %iface -p tcp --dport %port -j REDIRECT --to-port %rport"/' /etc/etter.conf");

# use
system (q{sed -i '168s/.*/redir_command_on = "iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i %iface -p tcp --dport %port -j REDIRECT --to-port %rport"/' /etc/etter.conf});
#-------^^------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```